# Почему получаю последний query, RxJava2

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Использую обычный `TextWathcer` , чтоб собрать `Flowable` вот так

```
private Flowable<String> createTextChangeFlowable()
{
    Flowable<String> flowable = Flowable.create(iEmitter ->
    {
        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence iCharSequence, final int iI, final int iI1, final int iI2)
            {
                isNoResultVisable(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence iCharSequence, final int iI, final int iI1, final int iI2)
            {
                iEmitter.onNext(iCharSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable iEditable)
            {
                if (iEditable.toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    mAdapter.realizeSettlementList();
                }
            }
        };

        mInput.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        iEmitter.setCancellable(() -> mInput.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher));
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

    return flowable.filter(iS -> !iS.isEmpty()).debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

И в `onStart()` подписываюсь на него

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    Flowable<String> flowable = createTextChangeFlowable();
    mDisposable = mPresenter.doOnQuerySearch(flowable);
}
```

Вот так

```
public Disposable doOnQuerySearch(Flowable<String> iFlowable)
{
    return iFlowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())//
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//
                    .doOnNext(iConsumer -> mListener.realizeSettlementList())//
                    .doOnNext(iConsumer -> mListener.setProgressBar(true))//
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.single())//
                    .map(iQuery -> mSearchEngine.search(iQuery))//
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//
                    .subscribe(//
                            iFilteredList ->
                            {
                                mListener.setProgressBar(false);
                                mListener.setFilteredList(iFilteredList);
                            }//
                    );
}
```

Теперь, что получается, когда юзер вводит букву делаем выборку и показываем результат

Если вводим вторую и букву, то опять тоже самое.

Теперь, когда я удаляю одну букву остается еще одна и по условию происходит еще раз выборка, когда удаляю последнюю букву то в `afterTextChanged()` срабатывает условие

```
if (iEditable.toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    mAdapter.realizeSettlementList();
                }
```

и выборка очищается.

Интересно выходит когда я ввожу (для примера) 2 буквы показывается результат, а потом я удаляю их не с задержкой, по одной, а сразу 2 раза нажимаю на кнопку стереть, то почему то делается эмит последней буквы ... и соотвественно я получаю выборку по последней букве, хотя в поле ввода на самом деле ничего нет.

Каким образом сохраняется и эмититься последняя буква при быстром удалении? Почему этого эффекта нет , когда я удаляю последовательно одну за другой, дожидаясь результата...

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Понимаю, что вопрос скорее всего для того, чтобы разобраться, [но](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/).

Comment: @post_zeew Ну как бы и разобраться тоже... Но и в целом мне не нужно такое поведение, когда в поле ввода ничего нет, а выборка показывается... Как то не логично выходит

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но по-моему filter(iS -> !iS.isEmpty()) все портит. Т.е. пустая строка никогда не эмитится и список не очищается, в нем остается последний результат по непустому эмиту.

Comment: @YuraIvanov нет, без нее все точно так же